# Why does malloc returns a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

While allocating static memory in c, it can be done quite simply. But while dealing with dynamic memory why do i have to deal with pointer. one explanation is that malloc allocates the memory and returns pointer so that it can be accessed but then why same does not happen in case of static memory?
Shouldn't it be simply accessed by its name?
for eg

```
int *arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Then *what* will `malloc` return? Can you write a proposed prototype?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @EugeneSh. Your estimation of OPs abstract language competence seems noticably higher than mine.

Comment: Static memory is also addressed using pointers as the compiler uses its address to read/write the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when a program executes `malloc(n)`, there is no name. It is not possible to refer to the object by name because there is no name that refers to the space that `malloc` allocated.

Consider `int *p = malloc(n);`. This assigns the pointer that `malloc` returns to `p`. Note that `p` is the name of the *pointer*. It is not the name of the space. `*p` refers to the space.

We could add a feature to C that lets us bind names to allocated space, so that `int &x = *p;` caused `x` to refer to the space. But that is not often what we want to use allocated space for. Sometimes we want to allocate many things and organize them into a linked list or a tree or other structures where one element of a structure points to other structures. We would not want to have an individual name for every structure in the program—we want to work with them dynamically, using computed pointers. For example, consider how we might add up all numbers in an array:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    sum += array[i];
```

We would not want to write this loop as `sum = array[0] + array[1] + array[2] + …;`. Aside from being tedious, we do not know how many terms to write at compile time. We want this loop to be dynamic, for the elements to be computed while the program is running. Similarly, with a linked list, we want to write:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int *p = Head; p; p = p->next)
    sum += p->value;
```

So we do not want a bunch of named variables for the allocated objects. We want to be able to manipulate them with pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The way you propose to handle pointers would prevent half of the use cases of pointers.
They not only allow to access the content of the memory referenced by the pointer,
they also allow to change the memory addressed by the pointer, i.e. which part of memory it refers to.

Accessing the content of the referenced memory is done like

```
int* arr= malloc(sizeof(int)); /* Do not cast malloc. */
*arr = 1;
```

Changing the memory which is referenced is done by

```
free(arr); /* assuming it was initialised as above */
arr= malloc(sizeof(int)*2); /* different now */
```

(*Strictly this does not guarantee the pointer to get a different value at the second malloc, but I did not want to make an example which leaks the first allocation by not freeing beforehand.*)

And also changing the accessed memory without changing the pointer:

```
*arr=1;         /* first */
*(arr+1) =2;    /* second */
```

Comment: `free(arr); arr = malloc(...);` can be shortened to `arr = realloc(arr, ...);`

Comment: I am staying with things OPs has demonstrated to be aware of, where possible. No need for additional complication... Not contradicting you however, @JL2210 .

Answer (score -1):

The way to understand "why does malloc returns a pointer?" is by understanding arrays in C. Array in c are sequential collection of elements. For statically allocating array we define as:-

```
int toys[20];
```

toys is an array of 20 elements of type integer. Here "toys" can be considered pointer and can be accessed like it.

```
*(toys) = 1; // setting first element i.e toys[0] = 1;
*(toys + 1) = 25; // setting second element i.e toys[1] = 25;
*(toys + 4) =  60; //setting 5th element i.e toys[4] = 60;
```

Now, looking into manual of malloc.

> void * malloc(size_t size);
>
> The malloc() function allocates size bytes of memory and returns a
>   pointer to the allocated memory.

Malloc always allocates memory in chunk (i.e, collection or array). so

```
p = malloc (8 )
```

allocates 8 bytes and return void type pointer of the 8 bytes, i.e. equivalent to static code below.

```
void test[8];
```

To get the pointer of desired type, the returned pointer is type casted as below:-

```
int * myToys = (int *) malloc ( sizeof(int) * 20 ); // same as, int mytoys[20];
```

PS:- Pointers and arrays are correlated. Malloc always returns array of bytes, so it returns pointer.